# Product id through data passed and multiple image in different array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**This is Controller**

```
public function products_details($id)
{
    $product_details = Product::where('id', $id)->get();

    $product_details_images = Product::join('images', 'images.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->select('image_path')
        ->where('images.product_id', '=', $id)
        ->get();
    
    return view('product_details', compact('product_details', 'product_details_images'));
}
```

**How to Convert in one array**

[image]

Comment: you cann call `->toArray()` to transform the collection into an array.

Comment: Are you wanting it to be an array for your blade file? If so, what are you trying to achieve that you can't with the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toArray()` of **eloquent** as below.
`toArray` method converts the collection into a PHP array.

```
$product_details = Product::where('id', $id)->get()->toArray();
```